# Detect if Facebook User is using HTTPS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, facebook-graph-api, koala

I have a process that pulls all of the User's profile photos through a NET:HTTP connection.  The problem is that I don't know if a user's account is using HTTP or HTTPS- the process works fine if I get this detail right. Is there a good, reliable way to have the Koala gem surface the user's security level?

I've been digging through the FB apis and cannot find any info on this. Hoping for some suggestions.

Comment: Use nmap to show net activity.

Comment: Why not just use the API to retrieve the photos?

Comment: I was hoping there was some way to use the graph api or do an fql query to determine if the user has a protected account.

Comment: @Igy, I have to retrieve the photos from another app that just has the references to the photo locations.  I'm using an FQL query to return the profile photo's "src_big" locations.

Comment: @Qumara SixOneTour, thanks for pointing that out, it's fixed.

Comment: I still don't understand the problem - if you're scraping via a browser plugin or are trying to automate login using the user's facebook cookies or username/password , it should still load, but over HTTPS instead of HTTP

Comment: Can't you just catch whatever exception occurs in your code when the request type is incorrect and try the other one?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by circumventing it entirely.  I re-architected the applications to communicate with each other, rather than each making their own requests to the FB Graph.

The app that connects to the FB api dumps the content I need in the db, then a request is made to the other app (with the id of the new record).  That app then calls back to the FB app, which provides a json service containing everything the other app needed from the graph. Completely eliminates http/https issues and authentication issues.